# Is it a good idea to write an OS in a scripting language?

Tags: scripting, operating-systems

Is it a good idea to create an OS that's written in a scripting language?

For example, how about creating an OS using Python?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190464/how-much-of-an-operating-system-could-be-written-in-say-python

Comment: There are virtual machines written in Javascript...

Comment: As good an idea as making a car out of all plastic and no metal.

Comment: Emacs is a nice OS, and elisp is a scripting language indeed, both by its use and its dynamic scoping.

Answer (score 15):

It's not just a bad idea. It's pretty much impossible.

How do you implement IO with a language whose IO facilities depend entirely on the host operating system?

How could you implement primitive scheduling without any useful interrupt primitives?

How could you write a device driver in a language which cannot address a particular byte?

Edit:--
Just to clarify a bit. You cannot write a "real" OS which interacts directly with the machine in a "scripting" language. You can however write a usable "virtual machine" if the scritping language is flexible enough. For instance implementations of Donald Knuths theoretical MIX (s) [machine](http://www.recreationalmath.com/mixal/) and a ZX80 [emulator](http://matt.west.co.tt/spectrum/jsspeccy/) good enough to run pacman have been written in JavaScript.

Comment: @ClintNash really?  JavaScript by Definition lives within a runtime environment that must run on top of an OS.  Sure, it's theoretically possible to precompile it to binary, but this is virtually unheard of.  Node.js must run on a host os.  JavaScript has no native access to the constructs required to write a real os.  Sure, once you are at a high enough level of abstraction you can start using scripts, but something below it needs real, bare to the metal ability to interact with the hardware.

Comment: I believe you are correct @bunglestink. I was referencing usages of JS/OS at a higher abstraction layer. I am uncertain at what level Windows 8 integrates JS.

Comment: Windows 8 - more specifically the WinRT runtime - provides an interface to use JavaScript as a first-class desktop application programming language.  It's a neat idea for drawing web developers towards the WinRT platform, but a far cry from using JS as a system lanague.

Comment: Lisp has no interrupt or IO primitives and can't access raw memory. It's dynamically typed. And yet, Lisp machines' OS was written in Lisp.

Comment: @nikie -- yes but it is not a real OS is still relies on the underlying OS for all the basic services.

Comment: @JamesAnderson: What "underlying OS" are you talking of? According to the wikipedia page, "All operating system software was written in Lisp" in LispMachines.

Comment: @nikie Lisp machines were built upon specialized hardware that basically implemented the Lisp virtual machine at the hardware level. So yes, in some since it is possible, but really at this point you are actually implementing your OS in the most primitive form possible - at the microcode level.

Comment: what do you think about https://micropython.org/ ?

Comment: To be fair Windows is written exactly like this. They just encapsulate native services in ntdll.dll, then expose an api, and after that, you may as well write in javascript. In fact, we are, essentially doing just that programming in Java, .NET, Objective C, or COM. All they do is have a server-client asynchronous relationship and pass user requests through layers of abstraction to the kernel, or reject it. COM's registry is nothing more than a really archaic JSON(inis), and better: javascript can read and write itself with eval and toString of functions.

Comment: As soon as you get to a point in your operating system where self describing objects are required(in other words, maps or tables), javascript is king of expressiveness at this level, with zero overhead(you would do the same thing in system api except you've seen what C/C++ "callback functions" look like, it's not pretty). Actually I wouldn't be surprised if well optimized engine JavaScript would outperform C/C++ at this level due to the sheer difficulty of expressing things that javascript users take for granted, such as callbacks, json, easy map access, self-description, etc.

Comment: That said, Python is quite far behind as a scripting language. It lacks native Promises, it can't get its' functions code back via toString, and its way of creating hash tables of functions is still medieval. It isn't that inconceivable to provide that functionality, but with python's syntax the code would look quite clumsy, probably not as clumsy as C trying to cope with asynchronous callbacks, but still clumsy.

Answer (score 6):

Before you decide on the *how*, you need to specify the *what*. What will this new OS do? Where will it run? Why would any one bother to use it? etc. The next thing is to determine the qualities of the OS. Speed, Security, Threading, Memory Management, Multi-Tasking, File Formats, Language support, supported processors, etc.

From answering the above questions and considering the many qualities of your OS you can determine what tool to use to achieve your goals.

Now, do you really want to do all that?

I assume that Python was used in part in writing parts of Linux - See: [What Languages are Windows, Mac OS X and Linux written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580292/what-languages-are-windows-mac-os-x-and-linux-written-in)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not a proper answer, but this project demonstrates a working operating system with a kernel written in JavaScript:

https://github.com/charliesome/jsos/

The drivers for VGA and the keyboard were also written in JavaScript using interrupts. I developed an implementation of OpenGL 1.1 for it myself a while ago and it works pretty nicely.

Comment: Actually that looks live the boot loader and low level features are written in c and assembly...  Also, the entire js virtual machine is implemented in c...

Comment: At that point you could also argue that operating systems can't be written in C, because parts need to be written in x86.

Comment: good point, can't argue with that.  Asm will always be required at some level; although, I believe that the only piece that absolutely must be written in asm on x86 is the bootloader.  After that, most C implementations have inline assembly features that could allow you to construct anything above that.  This is in contrast to a scripting language that always must have some lower abstraction of a runtime environment present, as it never touches the hardware without going through the runtime abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

**No, it is not even possible (exclusively)**

Why?  Consider the following:

**What is a scripting language?**

Lets make the following two assumptions about the definition of a "scripting language":

1. The language lives within a runtime environment.
2. The language does not have access to raw memory pointers.

**What is an operating system?**

Lets assume that an Operating System's primary goal can be simplified to the following:

- to provide an abstraction between user programs and the hardware they run upon

By these very definitions, it is logically impossible for a scripting language to be an operating system.  Why?

1. An OS must have raw, untethered access to a computer's memory for communicating with hardware.  Since scripting languages do not have access to raw memory pointers, they cannot do this.
2. Since a scripting language requires a runtime environment, but they can't talk to directly to the hardware, the environment must be coded in another language that has this ability.  In this instance (as is with JSOS that was brought up in other posts), a lower level language must be used to interface with the machine.

It is possible to write a minimum amount of code in a "raw" language such as C, but **a raw compiled language is always going to be needed by definition.**  Once this is in place, other pieces of the OS can be implemented in a scripting language, but a scripting language could never be used alone.

Comment: To be fair a typical operating system sets up a runtime for C, and exposes basic hardware abstractions before actually running C code. You could do the same by simply providing a JavaScript runtime. This runtime is a fair bit above C, but once it's up, it's essentially a modern Component Object Model, except JSON makes more sense than ini, and javascript is self describing by default, so you have no need for type libraries. JavaScript is so self describing that it can get object's functions via toString, manipulate them, and store them back on disk. It's not unthinkable to use it for a kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I must maintain that it is, in principle, possible to write an operating system in python. You would have to produce a Python-to-low level language compiler, as well as add modules to the standard library that provide access to the low level pieces of your computer. But if those two pieces were in place it would be possible.

However,

1. Its going to be really hard to write a compiler that produces efficient code
2. Python is going to be awkward for accessing low level details

Comment: Also, Python in this scenario would no longer qualify as a 'scripting language' by any sensible definition.

Comment: @tdammers, I consider scripting language to be an ill-defined concept anyways.